# IOS - Listen for whatsapp event notification in background

Tags: ios, xcode6, nsnotificationcenter, whatsapp

I'm trying to fire an event every time when the cellphone receives a message from *whatsapp*. I'm not sure if this is posible. This is what I'm doing so far to run a thread on background.

**ViewDidLoad:**

```
[self performSelector:@selector(MyFunction)]
```

**Method:**

```
-(void)MyFunction {

    sleep(3);
    NSLog(@"Hello World!");
    [self performSelector:@selector(func1)];
}
```

Now I'm waiting for an incoming *whatsapp* message using this code inside *MyFunction* method:

```
...
...og(@"Hello World!");
NSNotificationCenter *notifyCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [notifyCenter addObserverForName:nil
                              object:nil
                               queue:nil
                          usingBlock:^(NSNotification* notification){
                              // Explore notification
                              NSLog(@"Notification found with:"
                                    "\r\n     name:     %@"
                                    "\r\n     object:   %@"
                                    "\r\n     userInfo: %@",
                                    [notification name],
                                    [notification object],
                                    [notification userInfo]);

}];
```

But this last block of code doesn't work, is not printing anything. Maybe I'm not using the method correctly or maybe is not posible to listen *whatsapp* incoming messages. Has anyone been through this before? because a need a litle help here.

Answer (score 1):

`NSNotificationCenter` lets objects in your application send notifications to each other (You can also receive some notifications from iOS such as when your app is entering the background or forefround) but it is nothing to do with notifications that are displayed to the user.

On iOS an application has no access to user notification data. The only exception to this is when a user taps on a local or push notification that is associated with *your* app, you receive that notification in your `UIApplicationDelegate` class.

This means that on WhatsApp can receive notifications about WhatsApp messages and it isn't possible to do do what you are trying to do.